# Copy modified file from remote directory by polling every minute

Tags: linux, bash, sftp, scp

I have to poll remote server every minute and copy file if the file is modified from last time. I cant use 'rsync'. So the approach I am following is to poll the server every minute, get the file in temp directory, if it is modified, copy it to actual directory. Below is the code for that.

```
while true
do
  scp -pq ${SFTP_USER}@${SFTP_SERVER}:${SFTP_PATH}/${FILE_NAME} ${PUT_TEMP_SFTP_PATH} 2>/dev/null
  mododTime=$(date +%s -r ${PUT_TEMP_SFTP_PATH}/${FILE_NAME})
  if [[ "${mododTime}" -gt "${lastModTime}" ]]
  then
    cp -p ${PUT_TEMP_SFTP_PATH}/${FILE_NAME} ${PUT_ACTUAL_SFTP_PATH}/${FILE_NAME}
    lastModTime=$mododTime
    echo "Copying modified file"
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

I want help in 2 aspects:

1.In my approach, I am copying file every time to get the modified timestamp. Can I get that timestamp without actually copying?

2.I want to know how can I kill the script from outside(say another bash script i.e my kill job) by some operation like ps followed by grep (an issue I am facing is ps is showing me process name  as bash, so I can't identify the process exactly)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to copy. You are using `scp`, so you obviously have `ssh` available. `ssh` takes the command to execute on the remote host as its argument. So you can simply `stat` the file on the remote machine over `ssh` and compare to the *mod time* locally, e.g.

```
if [ $(ssh host "stat -c %Y /path/to/remote/file") -gt $(stat -c %Y /localfile) ]
then
    scp "your remote file"
fi
```

It helps if you have established public-key/private-key passwordless logins to the remote host. If not, there are many howtos available.

Comment: Thanks David. The issue which I am facing now is stat is not available on the remote server. I am getting the error "ksh: stat:  not found". So I am trying again with the date ( ssh host "date +%s -r file). But it showing Invalid character in date/time specification error

Comment: `date +%s -r file` should work fine as well -- should would be nice to have `rsync`. Is there some reason you don't have it on the local box? It doesn't have to be on the remote.

Comment: the system on which I am working is legacy production system, which has very limited privilege to install anything. So have to use old pre-approved tools only.